# Old redundant Windows 10 boot manager entries after clean installation

Tags: boot, windows-10, multi-boot, gpt, boot-manager

I wiped my drive (/dev/sda) which contained previous Windows 10 installation by using `gdisk` in Arch (which is installed on /dev/sdb) and choosing `z` for zap (wiping GPT) and deleting whole partitions by choosing the `o` option.

Then I tried a clean installation of Windows 10 on that empty drive (/dev/sda).

However, as you can see on the picture, Windows 10 still somehow magically finds entries of previous Windows 10 installations, even though I wiped my drives entirely.

I read about `bcdedit`, but where does windows' boot manager get the information from? Can this information somehow be stored on /dev/sdb?

I /dev/sda several times, and still it manages to get the information about previous installations.

[image]

Comment: I wonder if it has anything to do with your UEFI. Check whether there are leftover UEFI boot entries as well with `efibootmgr`.

Comment: I did forget to mention that I also deleted the Windows Bootmanager UEFI entry through UEFI/BIOS interface. `efibootmgr` does the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not all that familiar with the Windows boot manager; however, your description makes it sound as if it's reading data from the EFI's boot manager store in NVRAM. You can access this boot list in a number of ways, including:

- `bcdedit` in Windows -- I'm unfamiliar with the details of this approach, beyond adding new entries.
- [EasyUEFI](http://www.easyuefi.com/index-us.html) in Windows -- This third-party tool presents a GUI menu in which you can add, delete, and re-order boot entries. It's likely to be the easiest one for you to use and experiment.
- `efibootmgr` in Linux -- This tool does what EasyUEFI does, but in a text-mode way from Linux. Since you mentioned Arch Linux, check the [Arch wiki entry on `efibootmgr`](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Unified_Extensible_Firmware_Interface#efibootmgr) for details.
- `bcfg` in an EFI shell -- If you run an EFI shell (v2, not the older v1), the `bcfg` command can be useful. The [Arch wiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Unified_Extensible_Firmware_Interface#bcfg) also has information on this command.